# How To change NSMutableFontAttributes based on their previous HTML elements Swift

Tags: html, ios, swift3, nsattributedstring, uifont

I am working on a RSS app, and am trying to convert all of the HTML that I get from my RSS library into a NSMutableAttributedString with specified attributes for each corresponding HTML element, so I can display it in a UITextView.

For example:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p> *has the font* UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
```

and

```
<h1>Lorem Ipsum </p> *has the font* UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
```

Currently I am converting my HTML to a attributed string with an extension

```
extension String {
    var htmlAttributedString: NSMutableAttributedString? {
        do {
            let attrStr = try NSMutableAttributedString(
                data: (self.data(using: String.Encoding.unicode, allowLossyConversion: true)!),
                options: [ NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType],
                documentAttributes: nil)
            return attrStr
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And then I can enumerate over the attributes via:

```
htmlText.enumerateAttributes(in: fullRange, options: [], using: {
    attrs, range, _ in
    for (attribute, object) in attrs {
        if attribute == NSFontAttributeName {
            htmlText.removeAttribute(attribute, range: range)
            htmlText.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0), range: range)
        }
    }
})
```

This gets me to the point where I can create a string that can fill up the UITextView and the ability to update the attributes of that string, but what I can not figure out how to actually differentiate between different HTML elements so I can give them each the corresponding attributes.

Comment: Why would you want to change any attributes? Using your extension you can directly display `HTML` formatted text on a `UITextView`.

Comment: Hi David. I am trying to change the font styles of the HTML. All of the HTML comes from the actual webpages themself, so they all have different inline styles that I want to update to the styles I choose

Comment: It's unclear how you are supposed to know which style is which style. If you don't know your self, I'd go by listing first ALL the different fonts, then sort them (by bold, then size). Reenumerate and add a custom attribute "MyCustomAttributeName" with the value (the index of the font in your previous sorted array). Now, you can enumerate all of theses and change them? But clearly, the usual way would be to increase/decrease them with a multiplier, with `(object as UIFont).fontWithSize:object.pointSize*multiplier)`in pseudo code.